# Is Varnish in cloudControl ignoring the new Google Universal Analytics cookies ("_ga")?

Tags: google-analytics, varnish, cloudcontrol

So I'm trying to get Varnish "HITS" in a simple testing page made with Silex.
The Response has the necessary headers for being cached, but it is not being cached. It seems to be because Google Analytics is installed.

Is there a way to tell Varnish (in cloudControl) to ignore the Google Analytics cookies?

View test site here: http://www.delphinedhaenens.be (MISS)

---

**Update**: without the Analytics code the cache HITS, so I'm thinking that maybe cloudControl is not ignoring the new Universal Analytics cookies ("_ga.")... can somebody from cloudControl confirm this?

View same site with **NO** GA code: http://ga-delphius.cloudcontrolled.com (HIT)

And the same, with **Classic** GA code: http://gaclassic-delphius.cloudcontrolled.com (HIT)

Comment: Actually GA should not be a problem, since varnish strips GA cookies from the request so it should be cacheable.

Comment: Is the new Google Universal Analytics cookie ignored too? I've noticed that there is only one cookie now: "_ga." and the ones from before are not used anymore: "__utma", "__utmb", "__utmc", "__utmz", "__utmv"... [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains) vs [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/cookie-usage)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mkorszun ; can you confirm that both old cookies (__utm*) and new cookie (_ga) are being ignored by Varnish? The example site is dead simple and that's the only variable between the two links I've added in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Varnish keeps missing cache ,cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192924/varnish-keeps-missing-cache-cookies)

Comment: @eillarra, you are right, we exclude the __utm* cookies, but not yet the _ga - we will fix it and come back to you - thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cloudcontrol routing tier](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#routing-tier) (*.cloudcontrolled.com) is handling also GA universal cookies from today. Please have a look at simple examples:

http://classic-gacachingtest.cloudcontrolled.com/

http://universal-gacachingtest.cloudcontrolled.com/

What is interesting [official varnish documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/cookies.html) suggests using the rule which will handle all types of GA cookies but will also strip other types of cookies as well if only they start with "_" which is not so cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `__utm` cookies set by GA from client request in `vcl_recv` like this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|; ) *__utm.=[^;]+;? *", "\1");
    }
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^[\s;]*$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
```

This will remove all `__utma`, `__utmb`, `__utmc` cookies and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is already configured in cloudControl / Varnish. They just need to add the new `_ga` cookie to the configuration, but they are aware of it (view comment by @mkorszun).