# Varnish nginx caching issue

Tags: nginx, varnish

I just installed Varnish cache on a fresh Ubuntu instance. Varnish is working and I have it properly looking at my other Nginx server. The problem that I'm encountering is that the caching does not seem to be working. When I visit the Varnish site, I see the following statistics:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=180, public
Via 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache MISS
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

As you can see from the information above, caching is set to "public", and ample time has been given for the cache.

What are the next steps that I should be looking at for configuring the Varnish cache and ensuring that it will actually cache my pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Varnish keeps missing cache ,cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192924/varnish-keeps-missing-cache-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cookies -- unset req.http.cookie;